# Let $A$ denote the quotient ring $\frac{\mathbb{Q}[X]}{\langle X^3 \rangle}$ then which of the following are true

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, proof-verification

Let $A$ denote the quotient ring $\frac{\mathbb{Q}[X]}{\langle X^3 \rangle}$ then which of the following are true:

(A) There are exactly three distinct proper ideals in $A$

(B) There is only one prime ideal in $A$.

(C) $A$ is an integral domain.

(D) Let $f,g \in \mathbb{Q}[X]$ such that $\bar{f}\bar{g}=0$ in $A$, ($\bar{f},\bar{g}$ denotes the image of $f,g$ in $A$) then $f(0)g(0)=0$.

**So here is my answer**

**(A) is true** because $\langle X \rangle$, $\langle X^2 \rangle$ and $\langle X^3 \rangle = 0$ are the only proper ieals.

**(B) is true** because $\langle X \rangle$ is the only prime ideal.

**(C) is not true** because $\langle X^3 \rangle$ is not prime in  $\mathbb{Q}[X]$ hence $\frac{\mathbb{Q}[X]}{\langle X^3 \rangle}$ is not a domain.

**(D) is true** because the factors of $X^3$ are $X , X^2$.

Am I right in my assertions. Please verify!

Comment: Your assertions are fine.

Comment: Surely $\langle X \rangle = \langle X^2 \rangle$ since $X^2 \times X^2 = X^4 \equiv X \mod{X^3}$ so the first part is false?

Comment: @MattB What you say is not true. $X^4 \not \equiv X \pmod{X^3}$.  In fact $X^4 \equiv X^3 \cdot X \equiv 0 \cdot X \equiv 0 \pmod{X^3}$.  $X \notin \langle X^2 \rangle$, so $\langle X \rangle \neq \langle X^2 \rangle$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The conclusions for the first three are fine, but hopefully these are not the answers you are submitting to a teacher. They really need more justification than you've given. Here are some recommendations:

For (A): appeal to the fact that $\Bbb Q[X]$ is a principal ideal domain, and that the ideals containing $X^3$ correspond to the divisors of $X^3$.

For (B): There are so few ideals, so it is no problem to give explicit examples why $(X^3)$ and $(X^2)$ aren't prime. Then, argue that $\Bbb Q[X]/(X)$ is an integral domain to prove $(X)$ is prime.

For (C): You can appeal directly to your example given in (B) as to why it is not prime, and then this is airtight.

(D) Needs a lot more attention from you. What you have written is not a coherent justification by any means. You could, for example, argue that the hypothesis means that $X^3$ divides $f(X)g(X)$ in $\Bbb Q[X]$, and since $X$ is prime in $\Bbb Q[X]$, $X$ divides one of $f$ or $g$, say $f$. This should tell you immediately what $f(0)$ is, and it does not matter at all what $g(0)$ is at that point.

Comment: The $X^3$ and $X^2$ are not prime because they can be written as $X^2=X*X$ and $X^3=X^2 *X$?

Comment: @TheStudent not just that, but along with the fact that $(x)\neq(x^2)$, yes.

Comment: sorry,but i did't get this fact ,$(x)$ can never equal to $(x^2)$

Comment: @TheStudent that is incorrect, in general, but true in this ring. In some rings $x=x^2$ and $(x^2)$ can be prime.  For example, consider $(1,0)$ in $F\times F$ for any field $F$.

Comment: @rschwieb I am having hard time understanding why do we consider the ideals containing $X^3$? We are looking into the ideals for the Quotient ring $ \frac{\mathbb{Q}[X]}{<X^3>} $. Please clarify this.

Comment: @Kashif Tobreqson about the quotient, you reason about $\mathbb Q[x]$ and the ideals containing $X^3$. Reread D in the original post!